# What would be the PHP equivalent of this Perl regex?

Tags: php, regex, perl

What would be the PHP equivalent of this Perl regex?

```
if (/^([a-z0-9-]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$/
  and $1 ne "global" and $1 ne "") {
    print " <tr>\n";
    print "    <td>$1</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$2</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$3</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$4</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$5</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$6</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$7</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$8</td>\n";
    print " </tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you read any documentation?: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

Comment: Yeah, i just wasn't sure which one to use.

Comment: Wow. Only the first field is worth capturing, the rest looks like a big *split*--*and a standard one at that*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has some [functions that work with PCRE](http://docs.php.net/pcre). So try this:

```
if (preg_match('/^([a-z0-9-]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$/', $str, $match) && $match[1] != "global" && $match[1] != "") {
    print " <tr>\n";
    print "    <td>$match[1]</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$match[2]</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$match[3]</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$match[4]</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$match[5]</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$match[6]</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$match[7]</td>\n";
    print "    <td>$match[8]</td>\n";
    print " </tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: You might want to check `$match[1]` is set before testing other conditions, to avoid notices / warnings on lines that don't match the expected input.

Comment: @Greg K: `&&` is a short-circuit operator in PHP. That means when in `A && B`, `B` is only evaluated if `A` is *true*. In this case `$match[1]` is only evaluated when `preg_match` returns a true value. And if `preg_match` returns a true value, `$match[1]` is set. So there is no need to check if `$match[1]` exists.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest that rather than using a regex, you split on whitespace.  All you're checking for is eight columns separated by whitespace.

Look at `preg_split` at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php.  It should look something like:

```
$fields = preg_split( '/\s+/', $string );
if ( $fields[0] == '...' ) 
...
```

Answer (score 6):

[preg_match](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Excellent. thanks very much!

However, in preg_match how do I do it like perl where you have $1, $2, $3 etc.?

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Read the docs he linked to: "If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on."